# Galaxy S2 is possibly bricked. What can I do?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, unbricking

**Background:**

1. Browsing on Chrome, device suddenly freezes. Hold down power button to turn it off.
2. Turn it on again. "Galaxy S2 i9100T" logo keeps displaying nothing else happens. Tried rebooting again, same result.
3. Try to do a factory reset through recovery mode. I notice that the progress bar freezes unlike the resets I've done before. Takes a while. I get a bunch of errors in red with `failed to mount on E/` and `invalid arguments` (this is the best I can recall).
4. Now when I turn it on the Galaxy S2 logo will blink in 3 second intervals.
5. Tried using Odin to root it and install fresh firmware (followed [this guide](http://androidforums.com/galaxy-s2-international-all-things-root/482994-rooting-galaxy-s2-dummies-guide.html)). I also used  Siyah v5.0.1.tar as directed. Using latest version of Odin.
6. After clicking start (auto reboot, f. reset time and PDA checked) Odin gets up to NandWrite. A couple of minutes later I get an error message that it failed.
7. After unplugging my phone will show `phone...orange "!"...PC`. I can't get into recovery. When I go into Odin mode it detects a custom binary.

I'm afraid that my phone is bricked at this point and I don't want to get myself into further trouble without consulting someone who actually knows there way around these things.

What are my options here?

(I would prefer to keep the stuff on my sD card but if it has to be deleted as a last resort then so be it.)

Comment: You could try the heimdall software instead of Odin.

Comment: Did you just remove micro SD card and reboot before doing factory reset?
Did you try to boot in safe mode before doing factory reset?
http://www.tested.com/tech/android/3071-how-to-use-androids-safe-mode-to-save-a-phone-from-boot-loops/